# submit and update only the checkboxes checked

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, post, prestashop-1.6

Hello guys i have the following problem:
I have a html table with the following fields:
`|checkbox | id_manufacturer | brand | homepage |`

1. The main goal is when homepage (0/1) has value = 1 the brand is showed on the homepage and hidden when it is 0...
   This is all working.
2. I would like to update the value homepage when the checkbox of that row/brand is checked.

```
<form id="formBrands" name="formBrands" method="post" action="updateBrands.php">
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="position:fixed;right:0%;top:50%;transform:translate(-50%, -0%);" value="Update All">
    <table class="table table-bordered scroll">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="">
                <th class="text-center">Update</th>
                <th class="text-center">id_manufacturer</th>
                <th class="text-center">brand</th>
                <th class="text-center">homepage</th>
            </tr> 
            <tr class="">
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="brand[]" id="2" class="checkbrand"  value="1"></td>
                <td name="id_manufacturer[]">2</td>
                <td>ACER</td>
                <td class="homepage">1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="">
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="brand[]" id="3" class="checkbrand"  value="0"></td>
                <td name="id_manufacturer[]">3</td>
                <td>VERBATIM</td>
                <td class="homepage">0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="">
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="brand[]" id="4" class="checkbrand"  value="1"></td>
                <td name="id_manufacturer[]">4</td>
                <td>EPSON</td>
                <td class="homepage">1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="">
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="brand[]" id="5" class="checkbrand"  value="1"></td>
                <td name="id_manufacturer[]">5</td>
                <td>BROTHER</td>
                <td class="homepage">1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="">
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="brand[]" id="6" class="checkbrand"  value="1"></td>
                <td name="id_manufacturer[]">6</td>
                <td>OKI</td>
                <td class="homepage">1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="">
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="brand[]" id="8" class="checkbrand"  value="1"></td>
                <td name="id_manufacturer[]">8</td>
                <td>SMEAD</td>
                <td class="homepage">1</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

then the action page updateBrands.php (this is for prestashop 1.6)

```
       <?php 
// connect to db prestashop
include './config/settings.inc.php';
include './config/defines.inc.php';
include './config/config.inc.php';
include './init.php';

// variables
$id_manufacturer = $_POST['id_manufacturer'];
$check = $_POST['brand'];

// query to update
$query = "UPDATE `"._DB_PREFIX_."manufacturer` SET `homepage` = '1' WHERE `ps_manufacturer`.`id_manufacturer` = '$id_manufacturer'";

// query bd way prestashop
Db::getInstance()->execute($query);

// script to turn back (url)
$var = "<script>javascript:history.back(-1)</script>";
echo $var;
?>
```

**The goal is that when I submit update all, then all rows checked will toggle 0 or 1**

Comment: What is the point of that `handleClick` function supposed to be? Why are you not passing any actual record ID along, how is the server-side part supposed to know _which_ records to update here in the first place? And you would need to start by naming your checkboxes something like `name="brand[]"`, otherwise all the submitted values will _overwrite_ each other, and only the last one will survive.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for your help, i've edited the code, but i need some help or lights how to achive my goal...

Comment: What value(s) do you actually need to identify the correct records to update? I see you trying to pass brand and manufacturer there; don’t you have an independent ID column to directly and uniquely identify records?

Comment: Yes @CBroe in (all) second td there is the unique id_manufacturer "<td name="id_manufacturer[]">2</td>"

Comment: Table cells don’t have a name attribute, and won’t send any value with the form submission. These would need to be actual (hidden) input fields. But then you still got a problem to correlate the data, because the hidden input fields would _all_ send a value, whereas only the _checked_ checkboxes do. So better without any hidden fields to begin with. Either put the record ID as value of those checkboxes, or use a naming scheme like `name="checkbox[12]"`, putting the ID into the brackets, if you need to submit a different value as well.